# How to use company module and departments module in Activiti?

Tags: activiti

I've been searching for a long time on the web. Please help or give any ideas about how to achieve this:

- `Activiti` only provides group and user, how to inherit the company and departments module of the existing system to `Activiti`?
- All organizational structure：`Company->Department->User`, and each `user` has a role.

Comment: Create a group for company > under which create groups for each department > put your users in their specific department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your company has an LDAP directory server such as Active Directory then the easiest thing to do is integrate into that using the out of box LDAP module. If you dont have a directory server and you have more than 50 users, then you need to consider one. If you still want to use the internal groups then you can create department group (e.g. c1_sales, c1_engineering) and assign users to these groups. You can also create company groups (e.g. c1) and assign the department groups to the company groups. Not ideal but shoudl give you what you need.

Comment: Do you mean the **second way** like this? `A user belongs to department group and belongs to a company group at the same time` Why is this **not a good idea**?

Comment: You can arrange users in groups any way you like but you need to think about maintenance and search efficiency. Hierarchies are used to simplify both of these factors. Whichever way you go, make sure you build a simple admin app to aid user and group management